# One terraform apply to multiple AWS accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I already have a way to deploy resources in another AWS account in Terraform.
I just input the iam_role in aws provider block, in my terraform module.
(PS: I already have the IAM role on each account created also)

That works well for one account, but now I have the requirement to deploy the resources in several accounts (not all accounts of the organization, but the majority), and I dont wanna duplicate my TF files.

Is there a way I can, in one "terraform apply", to provision resources in several AWS Accounts (maybe specified in tfvars files) at the same time?

I think its not possible to create providers (or switch the iam_role) in a dynamic way.

Comment: Yes, using modules, but your question lacks details.

Comment: You mean like `terraform apply -vars-file=stage & terraform apply -vars-file=prod`? Not sure I understand the question.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is workspaces https://www.terraform.io/language/state/workspaces 

In every workspace, you can set the `profile` for the aws provider with an environment variable that will configure which credentials will use

Answer (score 1):

You can use a shared module to describe the set of infrastructure you want to repeat for each account, and then call that module once per account with a different provider configuration each time.

For example:

```
provider "aws" {
  alias = "account_1"

  assume_role {
    role_arn = "..."
  }
}

module "account_1" {
  source = "./modules/per-account"

  providers = {
    aws = aws.account_1
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  alias = "account_2"

  assume_role {
    role_arn = "..."
  }
}

module "account_2" {
  source = "./modules/per-account"

  providers = {
    aws = aws.account_2
  }
}
```

This example is using [Passing Providers Explicitly](https://www.terraform.io/language/modules/develop/providers#passing-providers-explicitly) to ensure that each call to `./modules/per-account` will see a different provider configuration for the `hashicorp/aws` provider. That means that the declared infrastructure will be the same across all of them but each one will use a different instance of the provider with its own separate setting for `role_arn`.

Comment: How could it be done for a 100 accounts? I have list of the account numbers, all with the same role. I tried to pass it in the dynamic code and for_each and use the specific provider by the count number, however it seems that it will not work. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: If you have a large number of accounts then I would suggest writing a script to generate a structure like the above for each of your accounts. They'll presumably all be the same aside from the role ARN, alias, and module name so should be relatively easy to template this.